# Prevent drag helper from being added to sortable List using knockout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

### Issue

When dragging an item from the toolbar to an observation group the item is correctly added, but the  drag helper is also added to the sortable list.

### Desired Functionality

Drag an element from the toolbar onto an observation group. Depending on what type of observation it is, display the correct template for input.

http://jsfiddle.net/PQL9T/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sortableList binding, looks like you want to remove the item at the end, since you will be rendering an item based on what you push to your collection.

```
            //Add Item to list

            collection.splice(newIndex, 0, collectionItem);

            valueAccessor().valueHasMutated();   

            ui.item.remove();  //add this line
```

Comment: Right direction, but I ended up putting the `ui.item.remove();` inside the if which checks for an incoming item, otherwise when sorting within a list, it removes the item on re-sort.

Comment: Updated with solution http://jsfiddle.net/PQL9T/3/